# if isset or empty equals var

Tags: php, post, isset

Is it possible to combine `$_POST` with isset in one row to avoid the error **Notice: Undefined index:**?

Example (doesn't work):

```
if(isset($_POST["VALUE"]) == "ON") echo "ON";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't since isset() returns true or false. But you can do the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['VALUE']) AND $_POST['VALUE'] == "ON") {
    echo "ON";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
if (isset($_POST['VALUE']) && ($_POST['VALUE'] == "ON"))
    echo "ON";
```